# почему данные AWS отличаются от моих?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, облако

На aws есть сервер. Во вкладке мониторинга в aws указывается, что нагрузка на процессор 30%. Но если я захожу на этот сервер (Ubuntu) по утилите htop я вижу что все 2 ядра загружены на 80+%. Почему так данные отличаются и каким верить?

Comment: а Вы уверенны, что это один и тот же параметр? я вот нет. Скорее всего они показывают нагрузку на процессор, а Вы смотрите нагрузку на выделенные ядра.

Comment: @KoVadim  спасибо. а можете объяснить в чем принципиальная разница? я думал нагрузка на процессор складывается из нагрузки на ядра

Comment: в процессоре может быть 4 или 8 или 64 ядра. и aws как сервис "нарезает" вам пару ядер от общего кол-ва, делая такую себе виртуалку. А другие ядра могут быть отданы другим людям

Comment: @KoVadim  т.е. то что в мониторинге от aws - это просто % мощностей которые мне выделены, а htop показывает реальную нагрузку на выеделнные мне ресурсы?

Comment: я давно работал с ними, не могу утверждать что это так и есть, Но представьте, что у Вас запущен виртуал бокс, в нем крутится что то, выделено ему два ядра. Внутри Вы с большой вероятностью Вы знаете только о своих ядрах. А внешняя система знает, сколько бокс потребляет относительно внешнего мира.